# Custom view containing custom views with custom attributes and styling

Tags: android, attributes, android-styles, custom-view

Normal styling for a specific View:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme">
     <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
     <item name="customDialogStyle">@style/CustomDialogStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="Button" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
      <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
      <item name="android:background">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<style name="Button.Dark">
      <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
      <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomDialogStyle">
      <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button.Dark</item>
</style>
```

Some custom attributes:

```
<attr name="customDialogStyle" format="reference" />

<declare-styleable name="CustomDialog">
     <attr name="android:buttonStyle" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Now with my CustomView:

```
public class CustomDialogContainer extends LinearLayout
{

     public CustomDialogContainer(Context c) { this(c, null); }

     public CustomDialogContainer(Context c, AttributeSet a) { this(c, a, R.attr.customDialogStyle); }

     public CustomDialogContainer(Context c, AttributeSet a, int d) { super(c, a, d); init(c, a, d); }

     private void init(Context c, AttributeSet a, int d)
     {

          final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.CustomDialog, d, R.style.CustomDialogStyle);

          // tried getInteger and some others too
          int style = a.getResourceId(R.styleable.CustomDialog_buttonStyle, android.R.attr.buttonStyle);

          a.recycle();

          Button bOK = new Button(c, attrs, style);
          // and tried
          Button bCancel = new Button(c, null, style);
          // even
          Button anyOne = new Button(new ContextThemeWrapper(c, style));

          addView(bOK);
          addView(bCancel);

     }

}
```

This is the very basic of my DialogContainer that has all the basics (Icon, Title, Cancel, OK, Container for other views). But what I'm obviously trying to do is apply a different style from reference to the buttons on the DialogContainer.

Doesn't matter where this is. If I create any other ViewGroup or so and want to add some of my own CustomViews to it, if custom styling can't be done this way then I have no clue what they thought while creating Android.

An activity with dark buttons and a bright Dialog with bright buttons - can't be too weird?
The alternative is to add say, all the attributes individually: background, textColor, textAppearance, and so on. I thought programmers wanted to be effective.

If someone knows how to do this, I'd appreciate some input.